# MySQL longest prefix matching on 1 million records against 3000 possibilities

Tags: mysql, sql, match, prefix

I have a table with roughly 1 million phone numbers and another table with roughly 3000 ISD codes (country codes). Now I want to match the phone numbers against all these ISD codes on the longest prefix matching.
In the ISD table I could have for example:

```
1     US
1808  US (Hawaii)
```

If the phone number is now 1223244223, it should return US, but if its 1808322353 it should return US (Hawaii).
What's the best way to achieve this at best performance?

Here is what I have so far. Unfortunately not pleased with the performance and I want to avoid functions:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `isd`(telnum varchar(32)) RETURNS int(4)
BEGIN
    RETURN (SELECT if(locate(isd, telnum)=1, (locate(isd, telnum)*length(isd)), 0) as score FROM tbl_ref_isd_v1 having score>0 order by score desc limit 1);
END
```

Furthermore I have this different function, which seems to be a bit quicker:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `isd_new`(telnum varchar(32)) RETURNS int(4)
BEGIN
    RETURN (
        select isd 
from test.tbl_ref_isd_v1 
where telnum like CONCAT(isd, '%') 
order by length desc LIMIT 1
    );
END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a query that does what you want:

```
select pn.*, max(ic.code)
from (select pn.*, ic.code, len(ic.code)
      from PhoneNumbers pn join
           ISDCodes ic
           on pn.phonenumber like concat(ic.code, '%')
     ) pni
group by pn.phonenumber;
```

Note that for initial strings, `max()` works because `1808` is bigger than `1`, and so on.

EDIT:

Build an index on `ISDCodes(code)`.  Then the following should work well:

```
select pn.*, coalesce(ic5.code, ic4.code, ic3.code, ic2.code, ic1.code) as code
from PhoneNumbers pn left outer join
     ISDCodes ic1
     on left(pn.phonenumber, 1) = ic1.code left outer join
     ISDCodes ic2
     on left(pn.phonenumber, 2) = ic2.code left outer join
     ISDCodes ic3
     on left(pn.phonenumber, 3) = ic3.code left outer join
     ISDCodes ic4
     on left(pn.phonenumber, 4) = ic4.code left outer join
     ISDCodes ic5
     on left(pn.phonenumber, 5) = ic5.code;
```

You need to have the joins up to the longer `ic.code`.

Comment: Your logic is working, but very slow (>80s on a small recordset of 180k vs 3700 isd codes). Compared to the function which takes 0,2s. Unfortunately the function doesn't return the entire row from isd table (what I would prefer).

Comment: The second query is by far quicker (also quicker than the function). Is there now a way to be independent on the ISDCode length? I have codes ranging from 1 to 9 digits. I added the additional joins up to 9 but I wonder if we could make this dynamic with the same performance.
For all additional fields I take from ISDCodes table, do I always need to use coalesce or would there be a better way of doing?

Comment: @DavidLaroche . . . I don't think you can make this dynamic and still have the queries use the indexes using basic SQL.  You could do this using a `prepare` statement.

Comment: I did it now using 9 seperate joins, this shouldn't change that often, so at the end it all works great and quick.
Thank you!